# Can anyone identify this plant from Bangladesh?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

I have taken the picture from an agriculture university in Bangladesh.

[image]

Comment: *Lantana*, likely *Lantana camara*. family Verbenaceae.  Famous for widespread distribution from hot regions to cool regions. Leaves contain strong fragrance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The genus is *Lantana*, of Verbenaceae. That particular one could perhaps be *L. camara*. There's a number of papers that exist which study *L. camara* in Bangladesh, just some examples:

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11676-007-0060-6

http://www.banglajol.info/index.php/BJB/article/view/1513